# Unintialized local variable, can't find the mistake

Tags: c, initialization

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning (disable : 4996)
int main()
{
    double F, C;

    printf("Enter temperature reading > \n");
    scanf("%lf", C);

    F = 32 + ( C * (180.0/100.0));

    printf("\n The temperature reading in Fahrenheit is : %.1lf", F);

    system ("pause")
}
```

> error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'C' used

I can't find the mistake in the program.

Answer (score 1):

`F` is being set a value, as in it is followed by a `=` sign, whereas `C` is getting its value from being passed as a parameter in the function; you must set its value to `0`.

Secondly `scanf("%lf", C)` should be `scanf("%lf", &C)`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning (disable : 4996)
int main()
{
    double F, C = 0.0;

    printf("Enter temperature reading > \n");
    scanf("%lf", &C);

    F = 32 + ( C * (180.0/100.0));

    printf("\n The temperature reading in Fahrenheit is : %.1lf", F);

    system ("pause");
}
```